# What is wrong in the activity_main.xml file?

Tags: android

when I run the app, there is an error message that the at line 44: error: mismatched tag
Can you tell me, what's wrong with it?
Thank you

I tried to delete the line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
app:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
app:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/colorPrimary"
app:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/white"
app:fab_labelStyle="@style/custom_fab"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    app:fab_colorNormal="@color/white
```

Error at line 44: mismatched tag
The seperate code line is the line with the error.

Comment: use this fab rather than app for set color:
fab:fab_colorNormal="#C0007D"

Comment: what line is #44?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `"` at the end of `@color/white and you're closing(incorrectly) the fab tag before it.
Try the following code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
app:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
app:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/colorPrimary"
app:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/white"
app:fab_labelStyle="@style/custom_fab"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Oh, my bad, I fixed the answer, check it out. Mark as correct if it works(or comment if you find any issues). Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Below is your solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/white"
        app:fab_labelStyle="@style/custom_fab" />

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fab_colorNormal="@color/white" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```